# Accept/Unaccept

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

Recently, I noticed something like this in my reputation tab:

> +15/-15 14:10 2 events 
>   [What does IN mean in Windows device driver functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615599/what-does-in-mean-in-windows-device-driver-functions/15615839#15615839)
>   +15 14:10 accept
>   -15 14:10 unaccept

So I thought, my answer was accepted and again unaccepted. But again, when I visited the Question, I saw, its still accepted.

If it is not unaccepted, why is the -ve reputation, and if it is unaccepted, why tha answer itself showing as accepted?

Comment: OP unaccepts your answer (-15). Then reaccepts it (+15). Net result: no change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was probably unaccepted *then* (re)accepted. You've got the timeline of events backwards.

To check this, look at the timestamps by hovering over "14:10". The unaccept occurred at 14:10:28, whereas the accept occurred 9 seconds later, at 14:10:37.

Comment: Thanks @Asad, The answer was previously accepted. Then unaccepted and (re)accepted. got it.